# How to show components tree in code editor?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to display to components tree in code editor in android studio :

[image: the tree i'm looking for]

`edit:` Fun fact: if I navigate a file at its absolute path (e.g. I click on an error message with a reference like `payment_view.dart:78:34`), I have the tree rendered:

[image]

Any (intellij) idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in: View -> Tool Windows -> Flutter Outline

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to get the tree in the editor view.
Like this : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/60894773/86502634-367e8d80-bd9d-11ea-934e-f2b45deae7b3.png. It doesn't show up when I'm opening Flutter Outline